# Doctrine not getting newly added record

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a function that does 2 things.

1. Saves an existing or a new item/record
2. Query and re-order items

The code algorithm is like this

```
public function doSomething($id = 0)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManagerFromSomewhere();
    $service = $this->getSomeServiceFromSomewhere();
    $repo = $em->getRepository(Item::class);

    $conn = $em->getConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    if ($id) {
        $item = new Item();
    } else {
        $item = $repo->find($id);
    }

    $em->persist($item);
    $em->flush();

    $items = $repo->getAllItems();
    // changes are saved to the database
    $service->rearrangeItems($items);

    $conn->commit();
}
```

Now the issue I'm having with this is that, if it is a new Item, when we try to get all items, that new item is not included for some odd reason.

I've tried stuff on my own and the one that works for me is to insert

```
$em->clear(); // after flush
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to approach this or if I'm misusing this functionality. It works though, when I tested it.

Comment: change  $repo->getAllItems(); to $repo->findAll()

Answer (score 0):

```
public function doSomething($id = 0)
```

There is $id is default 0, Actually, your are creating item every time.

```
  if ($id) {
        $item = new Item();
        $em->persist($item);
    } else {
        $item = $repo->find($id);
    }
```

also, you don't need to persist if you don't update or create new Item.

Or the way that I understood.

```
if($id)
{
    $item = $em->getRepository(Item::class)->find($id)
}
else
{
    $item = new Item();
    $em->persist($item);
}
$em->flush();
```